# Attaching action to button and clicking not firing event in MacOS app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xib

Very newbie question here...
I'm trying to attach a click event to a button on XCode MacOS application and this simple task just not working for me despite all videos and tutorials I watched.
Here's the code:

Test1ViewController.m

```
#import "Test1ViewController.h"

@interface Test1ViewController ()

@end

@implementation Test1ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(NSButton *)sender {
    NSLog(@"test1");
}

@end
```

Test1ViewController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Test1ViewController : NSViewController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

AppDelegate.m

```
Test1ViewController *vc = [[Test1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
NSView *v = [vc view];
[[self window] setContentView:v];
```

Screenshot of connection between button and method
[image]

What am I missing?
Any help will be appreciated.
A.

Comment: Is `vc` released when it goes out of scope?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean... how can I check it?

Comment: @Willeke, thanks - that answer really solved my problem (adding vc as a memeber to the class keeps it in scope).